# How can I display the location of remotes for a git repository?

Tags: git, git-remote

Is there a way to display all known information about a repository's remotes, either individually or all at once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy:

```
git remote show
git remote show <specific-remote>
```

Comment: you need to add `-v` flag to get _all_ the information otherwise you just get the remote names

Comment: `git remote -v show <remote name>` and `git remote show <remote name>` show the same info. `git remote show` is only for listing the current remotes.

Answer (score 8):

You can see the raw configuration

```
cat .git/config
```

or use the `remote` subcommand

```
git remote -v
```

Answer (score 1):

`git remote` should work in this case.

`git remote show origin` (or any other remotes you may have).

Answer (score 0):

This alias will give detailed info for the current remote:

```
alias showremote="git remote show $(git remote show)"
```